# Why IOS app is crashing while using Google Places API?

Tags: ios, swift2, google-places-api

According to Google Doc [here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) I tried whatever they said to do but all my efforts are in vain due to this error. But I didn't any change in info.plist.

2016-10-08 16:55:36.045 ContactApp[2674:83727] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSPlacesException', reason: 'Google Places API for iOS must be initialized via [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'

In my AppDelegate.swift I did look like below

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("**********************")
        return true
    }

}
```

and I simply copied code and pasted to my controller. Here is also a link of my controller [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23292859/)

what can I do? Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the statement and see if it is hit.

Comment: sorry I did not catch your comment. Explain what I've to do.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
```

instead of

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("**********************")
```